# How to write a table using Cloudera which can display values ​in smallest order permanently in Impala?

Tags: sql, pyspark, cloudera, impala

I try to write a table using PySpark in Cloudera workbench to Impala like this

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM tables ORDER BY a_column ASC")
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("temp.table_versi1")
```

I've made sure the a_column is unique. But when selected in impala the value comes out random and does not match the order by the smallest value in Cloudera. How to sort a table in a permanent way so I can display the value of the smallest value?
I've tried to use a PySpark query "Order By"
But this query has not worked so I tried to use spark sql, but still can't display the value that matches the order in Impala.

Comment: i don't think you can as spark will write multiple files for a table, and impala will read the files at random. you can, however, create a view using that table which will order by the required column(s) -- `create view db.view_name as select * from db.table_name order by order_column`

Comment: This is a good question. @samkart's answer is correct but you need to add limit claues. Else you will get `An ORDER BY appearing in a view, subquery, union operand, or an insert/ctas statement has no effect on the query result unless a LIMIT and/or OFFSET is used in conjunction with the ORDER BY.`  So you can use `create view db.view_name as select * from db.table_name order by order_column limit 10000000;`